# how Android paints a bitmap?

Tags: android, image-processing, bitmap

I've an app that processes a camera image and places a fisheye effect on a Bitmap. it works fine but is very slow at first until the effect is on the bitmap then subsequent calls to add more distortion and update the image are then quite fast. I first of all paint the camera image as a backgraound bitmap. I then create 2 subsets of that image from touchevents on the screen. these 2 subset bitmaps are then passed through a processing method then placed as overlays using the original xy cords over the background image. i've done some logging as the bitmaps are painted in the onDraw method and logged the start/end time of the image processing loop. it seems to finish executing the drawBitmap() method before the looping through the distortion method has finished? the screen is then repainted once the image looping has finished. i would have thought the screen would update after the drawBitmap method has executed. any ideas anyone? thanks.